# How to get the Latitude, Longitude at a X distance from the specified Point(Lat,Lng) in Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Suppose I give a Point(Latitude,Longitude) and a distance , How to get the Another Point which is at a specified distance in four directions in Android Google Maps?

Example I give a point LatLng(X,Y) and a distance 10 Miles. I should receive four points in all the **four** directions(**NORTH,SOUTH,EAST,WEST**) that are located in given distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) you can use the `SphericalUtil.computeOffset` method. From [the documentation](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeOffset-LatLng-double-double-):

> ```
> public static LatLng computeOffset(LatLng from,
>                                    double distance,
>                                    double heading)
> ```
>
> Returns the LatLng resulting from moving a distance from an origin in the specified heading (expressed in degrees clockwise from north).
>
> Parameters:
>
> - from - The LatLng from which to start.
> - distance - The distance to travel.
> - heading - The heading in degrees clockwise from north.

In your case, you will need to use four headings: 0 for NORTH, 90 for EAST, 180 for SOUTH, 270 for WEST.

Also, take into account that the distance parameter is measured in meters.

Answer (score 1):

the mathematical basis to calculate any distance is
Haversine
formula

```
a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)
c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
d = R ⋅ c
```

where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, R is earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km = 3,959 miles);
note that angles will be in radians and distance will be in km.

Answer (score 0):

The programming part for you question will be:

```
  LatLng toSouth = new LatLng(X - 10/alpha, Y);
  LatLng toNorth = new LatLng(X + 10/alpha, Y);
  LatLng toWest = new LatLng(X, Y - 10/betha(X));
  LatLng toEast = new LatLng(X, Y + 10/betha(X));
```

Now you need to know what the length of 1 latitude degree in miles is - alpha, and what the length of 1 longitude degree in miles is for current latitude - betha(X)(longitude is a little bit trickier because the ellipsoid of our planet is getting thinner to north and south by latitude, but latitude has ~constant length).
You also need to know what type of accuracy you need: a GPS accuracy where you need to treat the planet as an ellipsoid or just a sphere simplification is enough.
For simple sphere:

alpha = 69 (miles, approx)

betha = Math.Pi/180*EARTHRADUIS*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(X));

EARTHRADIUS = 3,958.8 (miles, approx)

For GPS accuracy implement formulas for ellipsoid from wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude